# Deployed my Angular application on GitHub pages but errors coming on website in console

Tags: angular, github, console

I have published my app successfully on GitHub pages, but my website is not displaying anything.

This is my GitHub repository link:https://karimkouki-bit.github.io/angular/

Errors I am getting in console:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () polyfills.c016570b002566700a06.js:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
runtime.b02196c….js:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
main.b2e32b70f6db51036a6f.js:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
styles.15af923bce632745f6cc.css:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
styles.15af923bce632745f6cc.css:1

[this is the image from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPgXJ.png)

Comment: It's looking for the JS/CSS files in the root directory. E.g. https://karimkouki-bit.github.io/runtime.b02196c5705ac0889a0f.js

Comment: What can I do ?

Comment: You should set the --base-href in your production build so Angular knows it is running inside a subdirectory

Comment: can you give the name of file plz

Answer (score 0):

If you work on nx project then

1. `nx build AppName --prod --output-path docs --base-href /RepoName/`
2. Instead Of Root Choose Docs in GitHub

Normal Angular
https://stackoverflow.com/.../angular-deploy-on-github-pages

base Url Example which created after making build :
[image: base Url Example which created after making build]